# Sticky div only for mobile phone / cellphones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the top I have two divisions, and the second one is supposed to get fixed after the user has scrolled pass it but only on cellphone.

Take a look at this for example : https://jsfiddle.net/livibetter/HV9HM/

This is exactly what I am trying to do but I want this to happen only on cellphone devices. On desktop the divisions will behave differently. On desktop top two divisions are fixed and therefore that isn't a problem and it is working properly.

On cellphone I have removed fixed from division one and 2 and when the user passes by division 2 I'd like to make it fixed and work like shown in the example given above.

Sample Codes from Fiddle

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
    } else {
        $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
        $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
    }
}

#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky.stick {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}

body {
    margin: 1em;
}

p {
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

Comment: if you want to target devices only then you can use `device user agent` to detect whether its device or not and then execute your function.

Comment: I tried setting a special css for only devices with lest than 768px but it didn't work appropriately.  I then tried activating that css after a certain height is scrolled.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried? Is it possible you forgot to put in the html <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> ?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use the media query in the CSS side to achieve this such as my example below:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 430px)
{
 .cssEntry {
  background: pink;
 }
}
```

**NOTE:** You can tinker with the mobile widths but generally 430px is more than enough.

Comment: This css will stay active from the beginning when the page is loaded but I'd like to activate it only when the user has scrolled beyond the second division. I tried activating a css once the user has scrolled past a specifc div but it isn't working somehow.